# Using the same figure twice with no new number

Tags: floats, labels

I have a figure that relates to two different issues discussed at very different point in a long document. Rather then send the reader back 50 pages to look up a figure, I would like to include the figure again at the later point.

However, I don't want it to appear twice in the list of figures or receive a new label number.

In this example, I would like it to appear in chapter 2 as figure 2.5 and again in chapter 4 as figure 2.5.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this? I am using Xelatex Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 from the Texlive 2013 Arch Linux package.

Comment: A simple approach is just to omit the `\caption` in the second figure, and replace it with a simple paragraph of text, possibly using `\ref` to get the original figure number.  But maybe you don't need formal captions?  Tufte (for example) has none in his beautifully clear books.

Comment: While either Thruston's or Steven's propositions will work, I just want to point out, that it might be confusing, if, using your example, figure 4.2 is followed by figure 2.5. If you plan a `.pdf` version only, without planning to print it, a hyperlink forward and backward for a reference and the figure is quite useful

Comment: @Hupfer, this is not so uncommon in technical literature, so I suppose my readers will understand. Also, it will be read in print, unfortunately.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi: My user name is Christian Hupfer;-) -- I wasn't notified of your comment

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `caption` it's easy to avoid a caption going in the list of figures.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcommand{\repeatcaption}[2]{%
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\ref{#1}}%
  \captionsetup{list=no}%
  \caption{#2 (repeated from page \pageref{#1})}%
  \addtocounter{figure}{-1}% So that next figure after the repeat gets the right number.
}

\newcommand{\fakeimage}{\fbox{Fake image}} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{A chapter title}

text

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\fakeimage
\caption{A caption}\label{figure:nice}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Another title}

text

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\fakeimage
\caption{This is for the new figure}\label{figure:dull}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\fakeimage
\repeatcaption{figure:nice}{A caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It's up to you whether defining a macro holding the figure to be repeated or one for the caption text.

[image]

Comment: Another good solution, that keeps the second image floating. I have a hard time picking an accepted answer here. :)

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi Figures should float: it's a lost battle trying not to. You can influence the placement when the document is in its final form by moving the `figure` environment up or down in the document. Trial and error is the best strategy (when one has the time to do it) for getting an almost perfect printout.

Comment: also true. I guess I will just throw a coin ;)...

Comment: Thanks so much. I think it's good to add \addtocounter{figure}{-1} after insertion of the repeated figure to decrement the figure counter.

Comment: Agreed with Sali Hoo! Just tested it and the counter still skips which is bad

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way, by stuffing the repeated figure content in a saved`\vbox`.  However, in this case, the repeated figure will not be a float.  EDITED to resolve List of Figures issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\savefigure
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\framebox{first figure}
\caption{First caption}
\end{figure}

\savebox\savefigure{\vbox{%
\centering
\framebox{second figure}
}}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\noindent\usebox{\savefigure}
\caption{Second caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\framebox{third figure}
\caption{Third caption}
\end{figure}

{\centering
\medskip
\noindent\usebox{\savefigure}\par
\bigskip
Figure 2: Second caption\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the second figure not floating is a plus, because the reader will not look go looking for figure 2.5 in chapter 4. Thank you!