# Image not centering in fullwidth even page

Tags: graphics, captions, vertical-alignment, fullwidth

My MWE is,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1cm,top=3cm,bottom=1.5cm,marginparwidth=5.5cm,marginparsep=1cm,outer=8cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength\fullwidth\fullwidth=\textwidth \advance\fullwidth by \marginparwidth
\advance\fullwidth by \marginparsep
\newlength\extraWd
\setlength\extraWd{\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup{margin={0cm,-\extraWd}}
\checkoddpage
\edef\side{\ifoddpage c\else l\fi}
\makebox[\fullwidth][\side]{%
\fbox{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=false,width=6cm]{example-image-a}}
}%
\caption{In the previous paragraphs, we mentioned the word “charge”. However, we need to look at its meaning in more detail.}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup{margin={0cm,-\extraWd}}
\checkoddpage
\edef\side{\ifoddpage c\else l\fi}
\makebox[\fullwidth][\side]{% 
    \fbox{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=false,width=6cm]{example-image-a}}
}%
\caption{In the previous paragraphs, we mentioned the word “charge”. However, we need to look at its meaning in more detail.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And no problem odd page output, exactly centering, {left space 10cm, right space 10cm}
[image]

But there is a problem even page. Not exactly centering. {left space 11cm, right space 9cm}
[image]

As a matter of fact, the image is 1 cm (\marginparwidth) left shifting. Or do centering of \fullwidth. I cannot do, a few days.

I am sure, easy for you but not for me. I didn't find duplicate another question. I found like its, don't working in full my code. Does anyone know how to fix it?

**Related:** [Let caption float into margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193753/let-caption-float-into-margin)

Comment: Should it center to the full pagewidth or to the textwidth part of it? For the full pagewidth, there is a problem, that your left and right margins are not equal, so it cannot center this way

Comment: pagewidth, that is [\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep] @Christian Hupfer.

Comment: You have a 'huge' margin width -- I don't get it, why you want to center it the page width then -- it would shift the image near the margin, which looks a little bit odd, I my point of view.

Comment: Like your writing, looks a little bit. So, never mind. Response received.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment

Comment: I am so sorry for my bad English. One moment, I'll write.

Comment: I couldn't translate that I will write. Exactly translate then I'll write. OK? @Christian Hupfer

Comment: Perhaps, it is better to show an image of what you want to achieve. Sometimes, a handwritten sketch is sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us analyse. First we add a `\fbox` around the `\makebox` like:

```
\fbox{\makebox[\fullwidth][\side]{%
    \fbox{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=false,width=6cm]{example-image-a}}
}}%
```

to get

[image]

for odd page and

[image]

for even page. You would want this box to cover the entire width i.e., `\textwidth +\marginparwidth +\marginparsep` which is true for odd page but not for even page. For even page, the box starts inside the text area which should start from the marginpar area so as to cover up to the end of text area with a `c`enter alignment.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1cm,top=3cm,bottom=1.5cm,marginparwidth=5.5cm,marginparsep=1cm,outer=8cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength\fullwidth
\setlength{\fullwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth +\marginparwidth +\marginparsep\relax}
\newlength\extraWd
\setlength\extraWd{\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup{margin={0cm,-\extraWd}}
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
\fbox{\makebox[\fullwidth][c]{%
\fbox{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=false,width=6cm]{example-image-a}}
}}%
\else
\hspace*{-\extraWd}%
\fbox{\makebox[\fullwidth][c]{%
\fbox{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=false,width=6cm]{example-image-a}}
}}%
\fi
\caption{In the previous paragraphs, we mentioned the word “charge”. However, we need to look at its meaning in more detail.}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup{margin={0cm,-\extraWd}}
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
\fbox{\makebox[\fullwidth][c]{%
\fbox{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=false,width=6cm]{example-image-a}}
}}%
\else
\hspace*{-\extraWd}%
\fbox{\makebox[\fullwidth][c]{%
\fbox{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=false,width=6cm]{example-image-a}}
}}%
\fi
\caption{In the previous paragraphs, we mentioned the word “charge”. However, we need to look at its meaning in more detail.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without outer `\fbox`:

```
\ifoddpage
\makebox[\fullwidth][c]{%
\fbox{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=false,width=6cm]{example-image-a}}
}%
\else
\hspace*{-\extraWd}%
\makebox[\fullwidth][c]{%
\fbox{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=false,width=6cm]{example-image-b}}
}%
\fi
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect working, This is it what I want, question [closed] @Harish Kumar.

Comment: Harish Kumar, Would you be interested in?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200519/subfigures-in-margin-note

Comment: @Özgür: I think the accepted answer does what you need. Is there any thing missing? Please let me know.

Comment: It's working. But figure number not increase. Body Figure 0.1 then does not margin Figure 0.2 It is not normally counting.

Comment: @Özgür So you want body figure to be 0.1 and margin figure to be 0.2?

Comment: Yes for this example. That is, up to from top to bottom, figure numbers is normally counting. For instance, two figures (**0.1** and **0.2**) in body then one figure (**0.3**) in margin. Another  example, one figure (**0.1**) in body, Lorem, one figure (**0.2**) in body, Lorem, two figures (**0.3** and **0.4**) in margin, one figure (**0.5**) in body... Maybe, figures in margin have sub figures (**a**) (**b**) ... I made a example that page, such as it.