# Repeat a table in a different chapter with same caption number

Tags: captions, labels

I followed the instructions in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200211/using-the-same-figure-twice-with-no-new-number) in order to reproduce a table from an earlier chapter with the original caption number and it works to call the page number of the original table and hide the new figure from the contents list but the caption number is still wrong. (i.e. it continues to say 6.2 and I want it to say 3.2.)

The only difference between egreg's answer and what I'm doing is that my original table and the place where I want to reproduce it are in separate tex files and are pulled together in a master file. On advice I changed my master file to use \input to call up all the individual chapters (previously was using \include) but this has not fixed the problem. Any ideas, please?

EDIT: Identified that the \thefigure needed to be changed to \thetable in order to apply to table. Sorted.

Comment: Well the example of egreg in the linked question works. So if it doesn't work for you you are doing something different, and as long as you don't show what you are doing it will be rather difficult to tell you where you erred.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've added more info to the original post but since I basically copy pasted the answer into my document (which is enormous) I'm not sure what other information would be helpful.

Comment: \input or \include are not relevant. egreg's answer works also with splitted documents. Did you understand egreg's answer? Do you know which part of his code is reponsible to repeat the figure number?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I thought I did - I copied the \newcommand{\repeatcaption} section without changing anything and replaced the \repeatcaption{figure:nice} with the label of the table I want to reference?

Comment: Hm. You are aware that `table` and `figure` is not the same?  Add `\renewcommand{\thetable}{\ref{#1}}%` to the repeatcaption definition (wild guess).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I didn't realise table and figure were that different. Changed that and it has fixed the problem. Thank you. I'm still new at this.