# Using the same algorithm twice with no new caption number

Tags: captions, algorithm2e, renewcommand

I'm trying to do something similar to "[Using the same figure twice with no new number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200229/127473)", but with the [algorithm2e](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) package.
Therefore I wrote the following code.

```latex
\newcommand{\repeatAlgoCaption}[2]{%
    \renewcommand{\thealgocf}{\ref{#1}}% modify the displayed label
    \captionsetup{list=no}% not displayed in the list of algorithms
    \caption{#2 (repeated from page~\pageref{#1})}% page reference of the original algorithm
    \addtocounter{algocf}{-1}% the next figure after the repeat gets the right number
}
```

Using this code with `hyperref` produces the following error

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text>
              \par
```

I have no clue how to get this to work, any suggestion is appreciated.

This is my working MWE (**without** `hyperref`)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
    
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
    
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200211/
\newcommand{\repeatAlgoCaption}[2]{%
    \renewcommand{\thealgocf}{\ref{#1}}% modify the displayed label
    \captionsetup{list=no}% not displayed in the list of algorithms
    \caption{#2 (repeated from page~\pageref{#1})}% page reference of the repeted algorithm
    \addtocounter{algocf}{-1}% the next figure after the repeat gets the right number
}
    
% \usepackage{hyperref}% The one guilty
    
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\begin{document}
    
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{my caption}\label{alg:mylabel}
\end{algorithm}
    
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{my other caption}
\end{algorithm}
    
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\repeatAlgoCaption{alg:mylabel}{my caption}
\end{algorithm}
    
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{my other caption}
\end{algorithm}
    
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: correct ouput]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could save the contents of `\thealgoc` (using an extra macro) instead of using `\ref` (or `\ref*`), for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\saveAlgoCounter[1]{%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname saveAlgoCounter@#1\endcsname{\thealgocf}}% save \thealgocf
\newcommand{\repeatAlgoCaption}[2]{%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\thealgocf\csname saveAlgoCounter@#1\endcsname% use saved \thealgocf
    \captionsetup{list=no}%
    \caption{#2 (repeated from page~\pageref{#1})}% page reference of the repeted algorithm
    \addtocounter{algocf}{-1}% the next figure after the repeat gets the right number
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}% The one guilty
% "hypertexnames=false" prevents the warning "destination with the same identifier (name{algocf.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored"

% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{my caption}\label{alg:mylabel}
\saveAlgoCounter{alg:mylabel}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{my other caption}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\repeatAlgoCaption{alg:mylabel}{my caption}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{my other caption}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: May I ask you why `\ref` or `\ref*` don't work?

Comment: `\ref` uses the aux file to get the information and therefore contains code which isn't easy to handle, at least not for me who isn't a TeX freak. Furthermore things like `\ref` do not deliver the needed information on the 1st LaTeX run. Both are reasons - at least for me - to store and restore `\thealgoc` on my own. (Luckily we don't need back references here.) So in short: I have no clue why `\ref` or `\ref*` does not work here but since I'm not a TeX freak I guess I would not even understand the explanation. But I'm looking forward to a better solution for this problem than mine.